# Django admin override field value using forms.py

Tags: python, django

I'm trying this:

in models.py

```
[...]
class MyModel(models.Model):
    firstField = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
```

In the db (an istance of MyModel) firstFied has value SAVED

in forms.py

```
[...]
class MyModelAdminForm(MyModelAdminForm):
    addedField = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['addedField'].label = "Added field"

        self.fields['firstField'].initial = "FIRST"
        self.fields['addedField'].initial = "ADDED"


    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

in admin.py

```
[...]
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('firstField', 'addedField')
        }),
    )

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Why after that, in admin, the form is rendered with initial value of field firstField SAVED and not FIRST as defined in forms.py (addedField is working)

Comment: Have you tried passing initial field value as argument in the formfield declaration ?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Comment: The `initial` value is only used when creating a new instance. When editing an existing instance, the form uses the value of the instance's field, so setting `initial` does not work.